# Can I acquire a Windows 8.1 licence by free upgrade from 7 to 10, then downgrading

Tags: windows, upgrade, license, downgrade

So, I have Windows 7 pro, and I'm looking to upgrade so that I can use some of the apps that are only available in Windows 8+. I considered just taking advantage of the free Windows 10 upgrade, and actually installed it at one point, but then I found out that there's forced automatic updates and decided that wasn't for me(I'm a bit paranoid after Android 4.4.4 killed Flash Player without telling me. :P). So, I did some research. 

From what I read, the Windows 10 upgrade "consumes" your Windows 7 license into a Windows 10 license, and so even if you revert back after upgrading then you can still change your mind later and jump back to Windows 10. (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-downgrade-rights/58e29e48-c1bf-456d-bd9f-c8917d9fb2a1)

I also read that Windows 10 has "downgrade" rights to Windows 8 and Windows 7, which to my understanding meant that if you have a Windows 10 key, you can also use it to install Windows 8 or 7 if you want. (https://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=Ci8rIKPyuSa)

My plan for the process is re-upgrade to 10, pull the license key, downgrade to 8 and use the license key, then upgrade to 8.1 via Windows Store, and end up on 8.1.
So my questions are:
Is this possible? 
Will it wipe all my data in the process?(not a dealbreaker if it does, but I'd need to know that so I can back it up)
Do I need to re-upgrade to 10 in order to downgrade to 8? 
Any input is definitely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just format and install Windows 7.  No; You can't downgrade to Windows 8, that only applies, to Windows 10 OEM machines your machine is a Windows 7 machine.  If you want Windows 8.1 you will have to purchase it.

Comment: A Windows 10 key cannot be used to install Windows 7 or Windows 8.1

Comment: This link indicates that if you upgrade to Windows 10 from an OEM version, you'll get a Windows 10 OEM version. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-10-downgrade-rights/58e29e48-c1bf-456d-bd9f-c8917d9fb2a1

Comment: And this is the link I was looking at about downgrade rights. https://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=Ci8rIKPyuSa
On second thought, I should edit these links into the original post.

Comment: Also, I already have Windows 7 installed. Forgot to specifically state that.

Comment: You cannot pull a key from Windows 10. If you go the upgrade path, Windows 10 will create a signature of your hardware and connect this to your license. So installation and activation won't need a key in the future at all.

Comment: So would the rest of what I outlined still work in that case, or not?

Comment: No. As stated by the others, Windows 10 doesn't include necessarily downgrade to Windows 8/8.1. So you either have to use 7 or 10. I know the automatic updates can be annoying, but from my personal point of view I'd still suggest to just upgrade to 10 and keep it.

Comment: No; You don't get a Windows 10, Wibdows 8.1, and Windows 7 key all from one instance of Windows 7.  Those downgrade rights are for the original version of Windows that came with the machine.  If you have Windows 7 installed the  you have exactly what you wanted, well, except the impossible.  **If you want Windows 8.1 you will need to purchase it.**

Comment: According to the first link I posted, upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 7 OEM should upgrade it to Windows 10 OEM, and according to the second link OEM versions should be able to downgrade. I understand that you guys are saying it's not possible, but I'm not really seeing the "why". Could you please explain?

Comment: You are allowed to downgrade back to where you started. The "upgrade" OEM licence is not the same as the preinstalled OEM licence. You don't get free reign to do whatever you want.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'd like you to post your comments as an answer so I can delete my cw answer. Then the Q can be marked as answered, ideally.

Comment: Your answer can be accepted as is.  I have nothing else to say on the matter.  What the author wants to do is not possible.

Comment: @Potatomaster. Read my comments again.  I explained in detail the reason you cannot upgrade to Windows 10 then downgrade that license to Windows 8.1

Comment: @Mokubai: Thank you, if someone had said that in the first place there would have been a lot less confusion on my part. :P Really though guys, it's not like I'm trying to steal anything here, I just wanted to know if it was possible. No need to be rude.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*Community wiki answer constructed from comments to question*</sub>

> **My plan for the process is re-upgrade to 10, pull the license key, downgrade to 8 and use the license key, then upgrade to 8.1 via Windows Store, and end up on 8.1. [...] Is this possible?**

No, your plan is not possible. Nowhere in that process do you acquire a valid license (key) for Windows 8 or 8.1.